# Do shaman spirit animals lose their spirit abilities while polymorphed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, polymorph, shaman, spirits

Polymorphing a creature causes it to lose extraordinary and supernatural abilities that depend on form, and class features that depend on form.

Do a shaman's spirit animal abilities fall under the spectrum of abilities lost when polymorphed?

Answer (score 3):

### Most Spirit Animal abilities are not dependent on Form

The section in [Polymorphing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph) prevents a dire tiger polymorphed into a chicken from pouncing on you, but probably shouldn't prevent a [Spirit Animal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/Shaman/#TOC-Spirit-Animal-Ex-) from functioning.

Notably, from the Polymorph section

> While under the effects of a polymorph spell, you lose all extraordinary and supernatural abilities that depend on your original form **(such as keen senses, scent, and darkvision)**, as well as any natural attacks and movement types possessed by your original form.

and from the Spirit Animal section

> A spirit animal is a creature chosen by a shaman to serve as a conduit, allowing her to more fully access the magic of her spirit on a daily basis.

The Spirit Animal is intended to be a conduit to a source of power, not the source of power itself. The form of the conduit is, generally, less important.

---

The other abilities of a Spirit Animal are based on the Wizard [Familiar](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar) abilities. None of those abilities should, generally, be "dependent on form" because all Familiars (whether they be a black cat or a totally equivalent greensting scorpion) they all benefit the same.

---

The GM has the final say on what qualifies as an ability based on form, because it is left open-ended. If they feel like being in the form of the animal that the Spirit "expects" is necessary for them to function as a conduit, that is up to them.

> While most of these should be obvious, the GM is the final arbiter of what abilities depend on form and are lost when a new form is assumed. Your new form might restore a number of these abilities if they are possessed by the new form.